# How to fix damaged avi video

Tags: video, vlc, mplayer, avi

I have a video camera that records video.

When I collected the files off the camera the video files that were recorded first play normally. The files that were recorded later give errors.

With VLC I get

```
Unidentified codec:
VLC could not identify the audio or video codec
```

With mplayer I get

```
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing SUNP0035.AVI.
libavformat version 56.40.101 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (adpcm_dtk), -aid 0
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 56.60.100 (external)
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 0.0 kbit/0.00% (ratio: 0->192000)
Selected audio codec: [ffadpcmdtk] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg ADPCM Nintendo Gamecube DTK)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
```

Both players appear to be playing as the playtime indicator does increase.

jpg images that were taken with this camera are also damaged.

I wonder is it each file that is damaged or is there a problem with the memory card.

I have googled but cannot seem to find a suitable solution for my situation.

Comment: Can you place a sample file online somewhere? It would be interesting to examine the file...